# Static background color with blinking font

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get text to blink with a static colored background, however both the red background AND the text are blinking.  The old `<blink> </blink>` tags no longer work.  I've been going off some existing CSS code I found, here's what I have:

```
<style type "text/css">
<!--
/* @group Blink */
.blink {
                -webkit-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
                -moz-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
                -ms-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
                -o-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
                animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
                0% { opacity: 1; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                50.01% { opacity: 0; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
                0% { opacity: 1; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                50.01% { opacity: 0; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
                0% { opacity: 1; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                50.01% { opacity: 0; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
                0% { opacity: 1; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                50.01% { opacity: 0; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes blink {
                0% { opacity: 1; }
                50% { opacity: 1; }
                50.01% { opacity: 0; }
                100% { opacity: 0; }
}
/* @end */
-->
</style>
<p style="font-family:Courier; color:white; font-size: 20px; background-color: #660E0E"><p class="tab blink">This is an example of blinking text using CSS.</p>
```

Comment: have u tried style="text-decoration: blink;" property..?

Comment: Add a wrapper and apply the background to it ( this way the opacity won't affect the background )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css you have works fine, it's your html that is off. You'll want the p tag to be wrapped inside a div or similar container. It looks like you have a p inside of another p which doesn't work. Try this:

```
<div style="font-family:Courier; color:white; font-size: 20px; background-color: #660E0E">
    <p class="tab blink">This is an example of blinking text using CSS.</p>
</div>
```